# SwipeRefreshLayout - Recyclerview scrolls to random position

Tags: java, android

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout which inside has a NestedScrollView with a bunch of other views, including one RecyclerView like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/mostLightGray"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //A couple of TextViews and ImageViews

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/services_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_mobile_service"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The implementation is quite straightforward, in the *OnRefresh* method I get a set of new results from an API, I remove all elements (aprox. 30-35) from the recyclerview and then add another 30 or so elements, lastly calling my adapter's *notifiyDataSetChanged* method.

When doing this I'm experiencing the following behavior: if the user swipes to refresh and leaves the recyclerview untouched (i.e. at scroll position 0), the elements are refreshed as expected and all works fine. But if, while getting the response, the user scrolls down even just a bit, when the reclyclerview redraws its new elements the scroll position sets itself to random position around the middle of the list.

I coulnd't figure out what was causing it, so I tried setting the scroll position manually, but it just gets ignored. This doesn't work at all:

```
mAdapter.setData(response);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: set: `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);` instead of: `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);`

Comment: You can try do following things:
1. Ensure that you are calling `scrollToPosition(0)` on main thread
2. Try to scroll on NestedScrollView instead of RecyclerView f.e. `scrollTo(0, 0)`
3. Add little delay to scroll invocation, so scroll will be executed after adapter changes are applied `mRecyclerView.post { mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) }`
4. Block scrolling when data is loading, f.e. by overriding touch listener on NestedScrollView